# Make the command bar unresponsive

Tags: javascript, css, ms-office, office-js, office-ui-fabric

I want to use office-ui-fabric with angularjs, so I am trying to use [ng-office-ui-fabric](http://ngofficeuifabric.com/demos/).

In the following [example](https://jsbin.com/nohiwoqawe/3/edit?html,output), when the wide of the screen is limited, we can observe that the `span` (eg, `3rd`, `14`) are hidden. This is not what I want; I want them to be always displayed no matter the width of the screen.

Does anyone know how to make the [command bar](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/commandbar) unresponsive?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/2.6.3/css/fabric.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/2.6.3/css/fabric.components.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngOfficeUiFabric/0.15.3/ngOfficeUiFabric.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="YourApp"> 
  <div ng-controller="YourController">
      <uif-command-bar>
        <uif-command-bar-main>
          <uif-command-bar-item>
            <uif-icon uif-type="save"></uif-icon>
            <span>3rd</span>
          </uif-command-bar-item>
          <uif-command-bar-item>
            <span>14</span>
            <uif-icon uif-type="chevronDown"></uif-icon>
          </uif-command-bar-item>
        </uif-command-bar-main>
      </uif-command-bar>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    angular.module('YourApp', ['officeuifabric.core', 'officeuifabric.components'])
    .controller('YourController', function () {})
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the text is set to not display in the css. Ie:

```
CommandBarItem .ms-CommandBarItem-commandText {
    display: none;
}
```

Then they using media queries to only show those elements when the width is over 640px
ie:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 640px)
fabric.components.min.css:6
.ms-CommandBarItem .ms-CommandBarItem-chevronDown, .ms-CommandBarItem .ms-CommandBarItem-commandText {
    display: inline;
}
```

You could override their styles by supplying your own that don't use media queries and just be sure that your css loads after their css (so it takes precedence). ie:

```
 CommandBarItem .ms-CommandBarItem-commandText {
        display: inline;
    }
```

Here is a sample app demonstrating this. Note that I had to add the styles in the **head** tag inline in a **style** tag b/c of how the inline editor loads its assets. Normally you would just load your own custom css in a **link** tag (make sure its loaded last).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/2.6.3/css/fabric.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/2.6.3/css/fabric.components.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngOfficeUiFabric/0.15.3/ngOfficeUiFabric.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    .ms-CommandBarItem .ms-CommandBarItem-chevronDown,
    .ms-CommandBarItem .ms-CommandBarItem-commandText {
      display: inline;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="YourApp">
  <div ng-controller="YourController">
    <uif-command-bar>
      <uif-command-bar-main>
        <uif-command-bar-item>
          <uif-icon uif-type="save"></uif-icon>
          <span>3rd</span>
        </uif-command-bar-item>
        <uif-command-bar-item>
          <span>14</span>
          <uif-icon uif-type="chevronDown"></uif-icon>
        </uif-command-bar-item>
      </uif-command-bar-main>
    </uif-command-bar>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('YourApp', ['officeuifabric.core', 'officeuifabric.components'])
      .controller('YourController', function() {})
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is how I figured this out. Using chrome dev tools, I right mouse clicked on the text and choose inspect. This shows the element and the styles associated with it. The default style was to have **display: none;** applied. When you resize the browser more than 640px wide, you'll see the media query being applied that now says to **display: inline;** the element.

[image]

Comment: Updated my answer with an inline demo. When I resize my entire browser those labels no longer disappear.

Comment: cool, it works now... how did you know it is `.ms-CommandBarItem` and `.ms-CommandBarItem-commandText` that control that part?

Comment: Added a comment + screenshot to describe method